# Records missing during select

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using the following JPQL query to fetch and sort records based on SSN. In DB 7 of them have a SSN and 4 don't have one. The first time I see all the 11 records being returned but when the query runs again, I see only 7 records, the records that had the case set to 0 and not the ones set to 1. Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT qd, CASE WHEN qd.ssn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as nullssn 
FROM UiQtrlyRptUnitDtl qd 
WHERE qd.emprAcctId = :emprAcctId 
AND qd.ccyyqId IN (:ccyyqList) 
ORDER BY nullssn desc, qd.ssn, qd.lastNa, qd.firstNa
```

I am using OpenJPA with JPA 2.0 and Websphere.

Comment: Are you sure `ccyyqList` being passed has the same value? Also, try looking at select printed out, maybe there are some difference?

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding... Yes Melnik. I ran a JUnit test trying to retrieve the records twice in the same method and got 11 records the first time and 7 the second time. The inputs were hard coded, so it didnt change. I feel like it has something to do with caching.